# Return date value into DateTime

Tags: c#, oracle, datetime

After i create an insert statement i want to know two values, the last inserted id and the date.

This is my insert statement

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO message (user_id, category_id, media) " +
    "VALUES (:user_id, :category_id, :media)" +
    "RETURNING id, TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(creation_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') INTO :last_insert_id, :last_creation_date";
```

The parameter

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter()
{
    ParameterName = ":last_creation_date",
    OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Date,
    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
});
```

When i try to get the date, only the year, month and day returns with 00:00:00...

```
DateTime.Parse(cmd.Parameters[":last_creation_date"].Value.ToString())
```

How can i receive the full datetime from the value?

Comment: you are converting from datetime, to char, and then to date. why?

Comment: Because when i turn it into a varchar2 (with TO_CHAR) it returns zero...

Comment: why convert at all??? add a timestamp parameter and perform no conversion

Comment: CAST(creation_date AS TIMESTAMP) still gives 00:00:00

Comment: I didn't mention cast. Nevermind. Point of diminishing return reached...

Comment: Even when i change the Date datatype to TimeStamp it gives no hours etc..

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

- Take a look at the docs for [OracleDbType](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleDbTypeEnumerationType.htm).  You are using `OracleDbType.Date`, which maps to an Oracle `DATE` type - which is just a date.  You should probably use `OracleDbType.TimeStamp`, or whatever type matches the column you're working with.
- Mitch is correct in the question comments.  You have entirely too much conversion to and from strings.  In the vast majority of cases, you should not use a string to represent a date or time in a database, or in the client code that communicates with a database.  Your SQL should change simply to:

  ```sql
  RETURNING id, creation_date INTO :last_insert_id, :last_creation_date
  ```

  Likewise, your .NET code should be similar to:

  ```csharp
  DateTime dt = (DateTime) cmd.Parameters[":last_creation_date"].Value;
  ```